# how can make a liktervise discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Can someone help me to make a linktervise bypass bot for discord.py I have this code that I found on github but I can't understand it

```py
import requests


def bypass(url):
  payload = {
    "url": url,
  }

  r = requests.post("https://api.bypass.vip/", data=payload)
  return r.json()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  result = bypass("https://...")  # include url to bypass
  print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to try and make it yourself, the people here won't spoonfeed you.

You could make a command that uses

```py
def bypass(url):
  payload = {
    "url": url,
  }

  r = requests.post("https://api.bypass.vip/", data=payload)
  return r.json()
```

and then check what the value is that it returns and send that back to the user

Comment: Thank you very much I am very new in the world of development I appreciate your answer a lot